# Update Access database using Visual Basic and CSV file

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to update a database with data from a CSV file. I have got this far but I am not sure where to go from here:

```
Dim web As String
web = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbol & "&f=a"

Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(web)
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim sourcecode As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

' Database connection
Dim daoengine As DAO.DBEngine
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
daoengine = New DAO.DBEngine
dbs = daoengine.OpenDatabase("Project.mdb")
```

Comment: Use OleDB ADO.NET provider instead of DAO.

Comment: I've been asked to use DAO specifically. I'd rather not use DAO, honestly.

Comment: So what is problem in this code?

Comment: Code Tips™: You can rewrite your code [like this](http://codepad.org/JVpy00gW) to take advantage of some nicer syntax.

Comment: @AVD: I don't know where to go from this, in updating the database.

Comment: Check this link http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_dao_csv_to_mdb.html

Answer (score 0):

You can execute sql against a database. Here are some notes taken from VBA:

```
scn = "[Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;DATABASE=Z:\Docs]"

''Example for simply importing from the CSV
ssql = "SELECT * INTO TestTable FROM " & scn & ".[Test.CSV]  "

''Example for updating an existing table
ssql = "INSERT INTO TestTable SELECT * FROM " & scn & ".[Test.CSV]  " _
& "WHERE ID Not In (SELECT ID FROM TestTable)"

''dao.dbFailOnError  = 128

dbs.Execute ssql, dbFailOnError
```

Comment: I have a question. "Where ID Not In" Looks like you're telling it to only add new records ; Does this code example actually update existing records with values from the CSV? 

I am tasked with a situation where I need to take CSV files, which will contain new records, and updates to old records, and import them into an Access DB, updating any existing records.

Comment: @DougRobinson you will need two queries for that, but it might be best to import the text file appending it to a table that you clear down each time. That way you can run a few tests.

Comment: I have no experience w/ ms access.... Is there a specific example you could give, or something i should be reading elsewhere to figure this out? I appreciate the quick response considering this topic's a few years old!!

Comment: If you are using MS Access, you can try the TransferText method of DoCmd https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx, but you will also see above a method of importing the text table with SQL. Comments are limited and I do not know what you need.

Comment: I opened a Question with my exact issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440734/update-existing-access-records-from-csv-import-native-to-ms-access-or-in-vb-ne?noredirect=1#comment52756258_32440734