# Update Existing Access Records from CSV Import , native to MS Access or in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv, ms-access, sql-update, insert-update

I am the application administrator for a ticketing system at my organization.
We're adding a new client, and need to import their customer records into our system.

However, we have been denied access to simply grab these records from a direct database connection.

We are limited to entering their ticketing system, and running an export of the existing records to a CSV file.

In order to make this work with our system, I'm taking these CSV's and entering them into an MS Access database, which our system will read and import/update records on our ticketing system from.

However, I cannot find a way to *update* records in the MS Access db from records in the CSV.

I can import records into a table, but it skips any records that already exist (There is a field included in the customer data that is being used as a unique identifier / primary key to distinguish new / existing records).

Any records which already contain this primary key are simply skipped, it does not update the records in the ms access db containing that key.

I do not have much experience with MS Access other than creating basic tables and forms; it's outside my normal scope of work.

I need to find a way to take a CSV file containing records that may or may not already be in this ms access db, and create new records if not contained within the CSV, or update records if they are contained in the CSV.

It doesn't necessarily matter how this is done, I could implement this using vb.net or a macro, if you could provide a way to do this with either.

I understand that this is a bit off-guidelines, I tried to find ways to do this on my own and haven't been able to come up with any code to test out and post as a starting point (my apologies).

Comment: read the csv into a DataTable, then you can UPDATE or INSERT as needed

Comment: So, import the csv into a separate table, and then ? Run an update query? I am unsure of how to utilize an update query to update the records from the original table using the records in this new table...

Comment: it could be a DataTable or an actual table in the DB.   Doing things like you describe for Tax Records has never been a one query fits all; there is always something special somewhere.  But yes, some would essentially be INSERT and some UPDATE queries

Comment: Would you know of a good resource for me to use to figure out how to do that, then? I guess i'll have to learn a bit more about access and db's...

Comment: I am confused why there are any matching records in the Access DB if this is an import operation.  Shouldnt they all be new/INSERTs?

Comment: There are a set of customer records on a system that we use..... We don't have an easy way to export them but need them on another system.
So, the plan is to export to csv & then import all existing records into an MS access database at first. Then, on a recurring basis, run another export to CSV  & import to access for any records that are new or have been modified. The data that i'm trying to import may include updates to data that's already been added to the db.

Comment: So, the first time that i import this data, there may be customer 1,2 and 3. The next CSV that I need to import may contain customer 4,5, and 2, with updated information for # 2. So on the 2nd and recurring imports i'd need to add 4&5, the new records, but also update 2, because there is new information for that record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you will have to do a series of action queries: append, update, and delete that use filters and joins. You can save queries as stored queries and call them by `DoCmd.OpenQuery`, or you can write them in VBA as strings to be passed into `DoCmd.RunSQL sqlStatement` or `CurrentDb.Excecute sqlStatement`

**IMPORT**

First, import the CSV using `DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim` into a temporary table. Be sure to clean out previous csv data from temp table prior to import.

```
DELETE FROM tempTable;
```

**UPDATE**

Then, update existing records between temp and live table but condition for existing customers in live table. In Access SQL, joins can be used in update queries but you may run into *not updateable* queries:

```
UPDATE tempTable INNER JOIN liveTable 
ON tempTable.CustomerID = liveTable.CustomerID
SET liveTable.Col1 = tempTable.Col1,
    liveTable.Col2 = tempTable.Col2,
    liveTable.Col3 = tempTable.Col3, 
    ... ;
```

Alternatively, to bypass non-updateable query:

```
UPDATE liveTable
SET liveTable.Col1 = DLookUp("Col1", "tempTable", "CustomerID=" & liveTable.CustomerID),
    liveTable.Col2 = DLookUp("Col2", "tempTable", "CustomerID=" & liveTable.CustomerID),
    liveTable.Col3 = DLookUp("Col3", "tempTable", "CustomerID=" & liveTable.CustomerID), 
    ... 
WHERE CustomerID IN 
    (SELECT CustomerID FROM tempTable);
```

Once done, clean out records just updated from temp table (to not conflict with append step and duplicate entries):

```
DELETE FROM tempTable 
WHERE CustomerID IN 
      (SELECT CustomerID FROM liveTable);
```

**APPEND**

Finally, append new records from temp table into live table but condition for customers NOT in live table which you can do with the `LEFT JOIN ... NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO (Col1, Col2, Col3 ...) 
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 ... 
FROM tempTable LEFT JOIN liveTable 
ON tempTable.CustomerID = liveTable.CustomerID
WHERE liveTable.CustomerID Is Null;
```