# SQL Insert only the rows that have data in a specific column

Tags: sql

I am basically a noob at this and have gotten this far from Google searches alone.  Access VBA and SQL inventory database.

I have a table that I populate by a barcode scanner that looks like the following;

```
PartNo | SerialNo | Qty | Vehicle
-------+----------+-----+---------
test   |          | 1   | H2
test2  |          | 1   | H2
test3  | test3s/n | 1   | H2
test3  | test4s/n | 1   | H2
test   |          | 1   | H2
```

I am trying to update 2 tables from this, or insert if the PartNo doesn't exist.

- `tblPerm2` has `PartNo` as primary key
- `tblPerm1` has `PartNo`, `SerialNo`, `Qty` and `Vehicle`
- `PartNo` must exist in `tblPerm2` to be added to `tblPerm1`

I can get the `PartNo` inserted into `tblPerm2` no problem, but I'm running into problems with `tblPerm1`.

I'm following user Parfait's example here, [Update Existing Access Records from CSV Import , native to MS Access or in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440734/update-existing-access-records-from-csv-import-native-to-ms-access-or-in-vb-ne)

I've tried an Insert and and insert with a join. The code below adds everything to `tblPerm1`, including rows with no `SerialNo`. How can I insert only the rows from `tblTemp` that have a serial number?

```
INSERT INTO tblPerm1 (PartNo, SerialNo, Qty, Vehicle) 
    SELECT tblTemp.PartNo, tblTemp.SerialNo, tblTemp.Qty, tblTemp.Vehicle 
    FROM tblTemp 
    WHERE tblTemp.SerialNo IS NOT NULL;
```

I expect this to only insert the 2 'test3' rows, but all rows are inserted.
`SELECT DISTINCT` is the same, but only one entry for 'test'

Once this is done, I'll delete from `tblTemp` and continue on updating and inserting. Maybe there is a better way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the `SerialNo` columns actually empty strings instead of NULL?

If this works, then yes they are:

```
INSERT INTO tblPerm1 (PartNo, SerialNo, Qty, Vehicle) 
    SELECT tblTemp.PartNo, tblTemp.SerialNo, tblTemp.Qty, tblTemp.Vehicle 
    FROM tblTemp 
    WHERE tblTemp.SerialNo <> '';
```

See [How to check for Is not Null And Is not Empty string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660203/how-to-check-for-is-not-null-and-is-not-empty-string-in-sql-server) for more on checking for empty strings, with or without counting whitespace (though details may vary depending on what SQL server you are running).

Comment: That was it, I guess it is the way I'm importing the data from the spreadsheet.  I'm using  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, [tblTemp], strPath, True